# Does it possible to perform Merkle root proof with filters?

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, proof, merkleization, sparse-markle-trees, merkle

I have a centralized e-commerce system with `orders` table inside. There are few order categories inside this system such as:

- Pending payment
- Pending shipping
- Pending delivery
- Completed
- Cancelled

I want to store all `orders` in a Merkle tree for accountability sake (maybe once a day).

If I put all orders under all categories above in one same tree, does it possible to perform Merkle root proof with filter as required argument?

For example, does it possible to proof order ID `1` under category `Completed` is part of the Merkle tree?

What I'm expecting is something like this:

- If supplied category is `Completed`, it should return `true`
- If supplied category is not `Completed`, it should return `false`

I read about Merkle tree, Merkle proofs and sparse Merkle tree. But I'm still clueless. I welcome all ideas from members here. Implementation wise, I can code Solidity, Golang and Node. The verification app can be in Golang or Node.

Comment: it's totally possible. You can hash the whole tree and perform all kind of queries. 
example of your leaf: 
`        bytes32 _leaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(keccak256(abi.encode(_category, _id))));
`

Comment: checkout merkle tree here: https://multisender.app (PULL strategy) feel free to use Kovan testnet

Comment: @rstormsf - thank you for the input. I'm curious, why we need two `keccak256` here? Thanks.

Comment: you don't have to have 2 `keccack256`, feel free to make a different leaf structure.